# "x Of y" style css, separator in the middle, vertical align to the middle

Tags: html, css

I have a series of articles to be displayed in a web page.

The articles count is a const number, say 100. I want to display an header with this template:

```
[current_article_index] / 100
```

The problem is when I style the slash separator and make it bigger then the numbers, the numbers are not being vertically aligned:

```css
#box {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
.of {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <span class="a">13</span>
  <span class="of">/</span>
  <span class="b">100</span>
  <div>
```

I have tried using table layout, but this cause the whole div being aligned to the left, instead of center:

```css
#box {
  display:table;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
.of {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.a , .b{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <span class="a">13</span>
  <span class="of">/</span>
  <span class="b">100</span>
  <div>
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` instead

```css
#box {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.of {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <span class="a">13</span>
  <span class="of">/</span>
  <span class="b">100</span>
<div>
```

Or because `span`'s are inline elements you can just use `vertical-align: middle`

```css
#box {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
.of {
  font-size: 25px;
}
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <span class="a">13</span>
  <span class="of">/</span>
  <span class="b">100</span>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply add `vertical-align: middle` for your `.of` element:

```css
#box {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
.of {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <span class="a">13</span>
  <span class="of">/</span>
  <span class="b">100</span>
  <div>
```

Comment: For some reason, in my original code(not posted), adding 'vertical-align:middle' to '.of' only didn't work. I had to add it to all spans. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 2):

You can add line-height to effect vertical align.

```
<div id="box">
      <span class="a">13</span>
      <span class="of">/</span>
      <span class="b">100</span>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
#box span{
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.of {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2axcLpa/)